# â€™ instead of " ' " after encoding with utf-8

Tags: python

while removing the /n from the text file, I was getting an output where "'" is coming as â€™. Eg, can't as canâ€™t. In some of your solutions, I saw that file should be encoded in UTF-8 format. But my file is already UTF-8.
Providing the used code for your reference-

```
path = (File_name.csv)

df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: How did you remove `/n` from the file? Using an editor? Using code?

Comment: Your file is probably double-encoded; someone took a UTF-8-encoded file and encoded it *again*.

Comment: Looks to me as if the Csv has a different encoding perhaps ISO. Some texts editors can show you the current encoding if you open the Csv with them.

Comment: If i encode it with `cp1250` and decode again with `utf-8` - `'canâ€™t'.encode('cp1250').decode()` - then I get `'can’t'` . It can means that you file is not `utf-8` or somewhere you used `cp1250` to decode it.

Comment: Can you please provide the proper code for this